# select(object,...) how to get the html options for this type of drop down menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using this drop down menu for my associations:

```
<%= select("price", "product_id", Product.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {},{ :class=>'chzn-select'}) %>
```

I was able to get he `:class` but **how do i get other options such as `:placeholder` and `:size`?**

Help would be highly appreciative, i cant find examples using `select` only after research.

---

P.S. Is there a better way to handle this? I am trying to make it more human friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By placeholder do you mean prompt?  In that case you'd put it in that first, empty hash, the 3rd argument, for helper options.  The fourth is for any and all html tag options.

Edit: By placeholder do you mean HTML5's placeholder?  Does that even apply to `<select>` tags?  In any case, the same options hash where you specified the class would the place for any valid HTML options.

There are some example in [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select)

For "better" options in this case `#collection_select` would be applicable, e.g.:

`collection_select(:price, :product_id, Product.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => true}, :class => 'chzn-select')`

"Better" is your call when it comes to Rails standard form helpers though.  They tend to be rather inconsistent and have about umpteen ways of expressing the same thing, so just do what you're most comfortable with.